# JLoader::import vs JLoader::register

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

Can You Please Answer What Is The Difference Between the following functions:

`JLoader::import` and `JLoader::register`

which belong in the **loader.php** file?

Comment: If you've found the answer to your question, please add it as a proper answer below ;)

Comment: Could you please add the correct answer below? It is for the benefit of others. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Jloader::import Will include the  whole specified file into our script and do some joomla specific naming conventions 
-> where as JLoader::register Will allows us To Include only needed class from specified packeg file and it also uses php's auto-loader that speeds up the app and save memory